# how jsdoc Classes with static properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, jsdoc

how i can get a valid setup here?
[image]

I want able to doc the `id` property with the static classes `_Test.list`
but am not able to found the correct way with intellisense inside vscode.
So all number not come from `_Test.list` dictionary, should give me error.
[image]

Any body can help me to format correctly this with jsdoc plz.
Sorry if is a noob questions, am starting with jsdoc.

```js
class _Test {
    static list = { a:1,b:2,c:3 };
    constructor() {
        /**
        * @typedef {Object} DATA
        * @property {_Test.list} DATA.id - id from list _Test.list
        * @property {_Test.list} DATA.id2 - id from list _Test.list
        * 
        */
        /**@type {DATA} */
        this.list = {
            id: _Test.list.a, // should ok
            id2: 14, // should show a error
        }
    }
};
```

I want proceed like that's because i need keep references features inside vscode.
[image]

Comment: Very minor side note: You don't use a `;` after a class *declaration* (which is what you have above). Also not after the constructor definition (nor methods). But you *do* use one after an assignment (in the constructor) unless you intentionally want to rely on ASI.

Comment: I put it like that for the example thinking that it would be more readable.
Sorry for this.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, i create a typedef where i want link `DATA.id ` to `_Test.list `,  I can not correctly refer to the static properties of the class, maybe I am doing badly.

Comment: `_Test.list[...]` are number type in this case

Comment: the issue is if i do `@property {Number} DATA.id ` i can assign any number example 12 ,14, i want error if i assign a number not inside the static dictionary `_Test.list[...]`
i update the message with more picture.

Comment: from my research i think it not possible

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18161

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSDoc doesn't have a concept of `as const` like Typescript does, at least in VS Code's typescript. But you can explicitly give a literal type:

```js
/** @type {{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }} */
static list = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
```

But it's way simpler to define your allowed values first and use them in an index signature:

```js
/** @typedef {1 | 2 | 3} Values */
/** @typedef {{ [s: string]: Values }} DATA */

/** @type {DATA} */
static list = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
```

Then you can use `DATA` elsewhere too.

```js
class _Test {
    /** @type {DATA} */
    static list = { a:1,b:2,c:3 };
    constructor() {
        /** @type {DATA} */
        this.list = {
            id: _Test.list.a, // should ok
            id2: 14, // should show a error
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: wow awesome , thanks you so much, i waste so many time to try make work `@enum` with vscode, your solution work.

Answer (score 0):

just want update
now intellisence support jsdoc mix with ts
so we can use
`@type {keyof staticList}`